# How to keep the same height of navigation bar under different orientation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I dealt with orientation by register as an observer, and rotate the navigationController's view to the desired orientation. But some view controllers deal with orientation changes by the following methods.

*[Responding to View Rotation Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926)*

- willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
- willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
- willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Those methods will make the navigation bar's height become thinner under landscape orientation, and I don't want this behavior. I hope the height of navigation bar never change. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by receiving the orientation change notifications at the root view controller, and then re-assign the size of navigation bar each time orientation change occurs. It works well not, but the official document discourage about setting frame, bounds properties to navigation bar.